Can we skip some documents in match stage of mongodb aggregation
for example while performing aggregation the last(previous) stage gave me this documents
{
 _id : ObjectId('662a416201ca2363543b6644'),
 name : 'location-1',
 startsFrom : 2,
 endsOn : 5,
}
{
 _id : ObjectId('662a416201ca2363543b6644'),
 name : 'location-1',
 startsFrom : 1,
 endsOn : 3,
}
{
 _id : ObjectId('662a416201ca2363543b6644'),
 name : 'location-1',
 startsFrom : 2,
 endsOn : 4,
}


the next stage is $match
{
 $match{
  "startsFrom" : { $lte : 2},
  "endsOn" : { $gte : 2},
 }
}

here as after comparison with the first document the match stage results in true . so I want to skip the $match stage for all other documents with same _id as of the document which completed the match stage and got the result true.
If this is not possible is there any other alternate solution to reduce the computation power consumption without changing the previous aggregation stages
NOTE :
documents with same _id after the previous $unwind stage might be
more than 1million and that too for multiple _ids .

You can group by _id and select the $first document. This will result in one document of the three with the same _id.

Can you provide the raw documents and the aggregation that leads you to current stage? It looks to me that it is a $unwind result and you may potentially reduce the result set before $unwind

I think OP is looking for something similar to Python's next() with a generator, or JavaScript's Array.find(), or Kotlin's .first { <predicate> } - ie an "early-exit filterOne". But they all require an array/iterable, so they need to be grouped together, not separate docs.

Mongo doesn't provide anything similar. Functional programming patterns would have us use reduce to achieve the same, which is what I've done in my 2nd answer.

Ok, here's an alternative which might provide some speed-up: Use $reduce to match each sub-doc until one is found, and then just keep returning the result without further checks.

Group your docs by _id or whichever field identifies them as being the same, use $push to put then in a field as an array: { $group: { _id: "$_id", docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }

This should look like the starting data in my example below.
You probably have an $unwind stage before that in your pipeline, remove it if possible; or group them again if not possible.


Then use $reduce in a $set, $addFields, or $project stage, to keep checking sub-documents only while no match has been found:

Use an empty object {} as the initialValue and if the current result of $reduce, which is available in $$value, is not an empty object, just return the current $$value without checking the current document.
If the current/running value is empty, then do the $match as a $cond-if-then-else



The $reduce-loop will go on until the last sub-doc in the array, but the amount of compute being done will be almost nothing once the first match has been found. However, you'll need to check if this is actually faster than using a standard $match + $group-$first as per my previous answer.
db.collection.aggregate([
  // put a sort & group before this stage
  {
    $set: {
      first_match: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$docs",
          initialValue: {},
          in: {
            $cond: {
              // check if a match has already been
              if: { $ne: ["$$value", {}] },
              // return the matched sub-doc, don't check any more
              then: "$$value",
              // no matched sub-doc, so check this one
              else: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $and: [
                      { $lte: ["$$this.startsFrom", 2] },
                      { $gte: ["$$this.endsOn", 2] }
                    ]
                  },
                  // return this sub-doc if it's a match
                  then: "$$this",
                  // otherwise return an empty object
                  else: {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$first_match" }
])

Mongo Playground

Finally having some time to go through your 2 answers. Detailed and well-explained answer as usual. I think this one better suits OP's need as it is trying to reduce the intermediate result set. On the other hand, I suspect that OP's current aggregation stage result is a result of $unwind from the observation of duplicated _id. I would suggest OP to reduce the previous result if possible in earlier stage, says potentially using sub-pipeline to minimize the lookup result if a $lookup is involved.

@ray Thank you for the feedback! :-) Agreed that OP's starting documents are probably the result of an $unwind, which I've mentioned in this answer; or even a $lookup with a pipeline + unwind, in which case that pipeline could also be used to get fewer results. In this answer, I've advised OP to remove their $unwind if possible before the $reduce, similar to what you've said. And most importantly, we cannot provide better answers unless we see the original data or the original pipeline OP is using, which you have also commented to OP, so we're on the same page :-)

You can use a $group stage with an accumulator of $first:
db.collection.aggregate([
  // start: example "previous stages"
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  { $replaceWith: "$docs" },
  // end: example "previous stages"
  {
    $match: {
      "startsFrom": { $lte: 2 },
      "endsOn": { $gte: 2 }
    }
  },
  // put a sort here
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      first_doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$first_doc" }
])

Mongo Playground
In the example above, it selects only one document per _id given; or any field(s)/expression which you pass to { $group: { _id: <expr> } }. In  your case, it is the _id field.
Note: it's recommended to use a $sort before the group so that you get consistent "first" documents. From the docs:

Returns the result of an expression for the first document in a group of documents. Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order.
To define the document order for  $first  in other pipeline stages, add a preceding  $sort stage.


i want to remove unnecessary computation in match query(filter unnecessary documents in match stage itself) so that no extra documents goes to the next stage

@reedrichards You can't just "remove docs" before the match stage since you don't know which relevant docs will match. If you first group by _id and then take only the first doc before the match, you could end up in a situation where the first doc won't match but one of the docs you removed before would have matched. Then what? If you are sure that any docs with the same _id will match your criteria then move the group earlier in the pipeline.

@reedrichards If you are running this pipeline with just one doc array unwrapped (so there will always be only one _id) , then you could simply put a limit stage with { $limit: 1 }. But it's VERY unlikely that this would lead to the correct behaviour. You try your luck with limit 10 or limit 100 but then there's no guarantee that you'll remove the matching docs and end up with 100 which won't match; and then you end up with zero results.

Another alternative with $reduce in my other answer; which removes unnecessary computation but might not actually be faster. You'll have to share some examples of your actual pipeline & data to see where the number of documents can be reduced.

You can try to write your own custom pipe like $matchFirstInGroup:

For map-reduce operations that require custom functionality, you can
use the $accumulator and $function aggregation operators. You can use
those operators to define custom aggregation expressions in
JavaScript.

docs
EDIT:
To the other responses: guys, you do not get that TS already groups the results after his $match pipe? What he wants to achieve, is cancelling the $match pipe because he wants more performance.

There is no such $matchFirstInGroup operator. And the link you provided already stated that map-reduced is deprecated and unsupported here and there.

It does not exist because I suggested to CREATE $matchFirstInGroup operator, lol. And yes map-reduce is deprecated, I know that. What it has to do with the fact that you can create your custom pipe?

So, can you demonstrate how to create such an operator through code example? Also, can you explain how does this solution address OP's scenario?

@ray, regarding your second question, I will quote OP "so I want to skip the $match stage for all other documents with same _id as of the document which completed the match stage and got the result true." - this is not possible with existing $match because it obviously returns all matched documents. So you have to create something custom, which would match and skip already matched documents by key. Currently I believe such thing will not be faster, than the native $match+$group, but that needs to be tested. I will try to update my post today with an example.

As an alternative, the $bucket and $facet stages look interesting. Maybe that would do.
